# C# SignalR GetHttpContext / HttpContext Response Does not Exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, signalr

Having an issue upgrading an asp.net application to use SignalR with WebSocket Protocol enabled. Beforehand, with just SignalR, I was able to set and add response cookies before the the websocket protocol was enabled. I've noticed now while debugging that with HttpResponse from HttpContext and HttpResponseBase from GetHttpContext, I am either getting a

> **Response is not available in this context**

or

> **threw an exception of type System.Web.HttpException**

```
 Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Response

 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies
```

Funny thing is, is that the request for of the context still exists and doesn't give me any issues. Also, this happens within the SignalR HUB classes. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that SignalR's underlying technology is different to MVC - there is no ability to set cookies (cookies are set in a HTTP response, but there is no such thing when using web sockets).

So, basically you can't do it. You can read cookies however (the cookies when the websocket connection was initialised anyway...), using the hub's context.

Comment: Thank you  for clarifying that!

Answer (score 0):

@thab's hint about using the hub's context helped me. I'm making a new answer to share code nicely. We're doing some funky things with DI and HttpContext, so here's what I did in my Hub:

Inject `IHttpContextAccessor` as `httpContextAccessor` (it should be bound to `HttpContextAccessor` but just in case we have `services.TryAddSingleton<IContextualServiceProvider, HttpContextServiceProvider>();` in our configuration), then in the method in the hub that processes requests (i.e. not the constructor), do:

```cs
var httpContext = this.Context?.GetHttpContext();
if (httpContext != null)
{
    // Set the correct context within the AsyncLocal that `HttpContextAccessor` holds so that we can use it when injecting via [our custom DI resolver].
    this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext = httpContext;
}
```